# coldfusion 8 cache cleaning

Tags: caching, coldfusion

what is the cleanest way to clear cache on ColdFusion 8 server
do i don't have problems with old Stubs when i create 
web service client?

ty very much for your response

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe Documentation for cfInvoke](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e0a.html)

Specifically, look at the refreshWSDL argument.

It's not something I'd call every time, since it adds a good bit of overhead to your WS instatniation.  However, having a scheduled task to clear and recreate a stub that may change, or using it during development of the webservice might be beneficial.